# Getting the second value from an array and placing it in a form field

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

I built a query that returns the values I require and put them into a dropdown list. When I select an item in the dropdown, I placed the value of the option into a form field.

**Now, I also want to place a second value from the array into a different form field.** (Ex. first field contains order number, second field contains customer name, and so on....) I can place plaintext into the second field but can't get the array value `$row[field_value]` to work.

It would work if I could run a trigger with the value when I selected an item to a separate php file to run a full query and return the result to the tom fields.

PHP:

```
$query5 = "SELECT customers.id, customers.email, customers_customfields.customer_id, customers_customfields.field_value, orders.sign_date,orders.sub_id,    orders.domain_name, orders.cust_status 
                        FROM customers, customers_customfields, customers_orders, orders 
                        WHERE customers_orders.order_id = orders.sub_id
                        AND customers.id = customers_orders.customer_id 
                        AND customers.id = customers_customfields.customer_id
                        AND customers_customfields.field_id = 1";
$result5 = mysql_query($query5) or die("Unable to query CPU parts");
$option = "";
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result5)) {
    $option .= "<option value='{$row[sub_id]}'>{$row[sub_id]}&nbsp;&nbsp;{$row[cust_status]}&nbsp;&nbsp;{$row[sign_date]}&nbsp;&nbsp;{$row[field_value]};</option>";
}
// close connection 
 mysql_close($server);
?>
```

HTML:

```
<!-- // ====================================================Select and input Order Number Code =========== -->
<form name="Submit" onsubmit="CheckForm()"> 

<select name="Orders" onchange="document.Submit.showValue1.value=this.value; document.Submit.showValue2.value=['Array Value']"> 

// <? echo $option; ?>
</select> 

<input type="text" name="showValue1"><br>
<input type="text" name="showValue2" ><br>
```

Comment: Any news? Did any answer help you or do you still have a problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add `data-your_value="$row['your_value']"` to each option and then try to retrieve this values with code like `this.options[this.selectedIndex].attributes['data-your_value'].value`.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/UVKY8/1/.

Answer (score -1):

i'd advise you to change this line

```
$option .= "<option value='{$row[sub_id]}'>{$row[sub_id]}&nbsp;&nbsp;{$row[cust_status]}&nbsp;&nbsp;{$row[sign_date]}&nbsp;&nbsp;{$row[field_value]};</option>";
```

into this one

```
$option .= "<option value='" . $row['sub_id'] . "'>" . $row['sub_id']. "&nbsp;&nbsp;" . $row['cust_status'] . "&nbsp;&nbsp;" . $row['sign_date'] ."&nbsp;&nbsp;" . $row['field_value'] .";</option>";
```